# how to get key-value in associative array?

Tags: php

I've an associative array:

```
Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 0 )
```

array will always contain only two.

The key is `user_id` and value is `status`.

I applied `ksort()` to the array, because I wanted lower user_id first in the array.

Now I want to grab key and value for each, (but I never know what key=user_id is):

```
$key_1
$value_1
$key_2
$value_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reset($array);
list($key_1, $value_1) = each($array);
list($key_2, $value_2) = each($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
   .......
}
```

Comment: I want them all at once.

Comment: plus how do I get $key_1
$value_1
$key_2
$value_2 variable names inside foreach?

Comment: @salivan You still can get the variable names, in price of writing code which is several times more complex than mine. Not the first time I see people votiong without actually reading the question :(

Comment: @mas.morozov Well, I cannot say, that the question is stated with supreme clarity :)

Comment: Now don't blame the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

```
keys=array_keys($array);
values=array_values($array);
```